# RUN mv - Directory not found at Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm doing a Dockerfile to construct a Gradle program at Cloud, I'm having an issue at the command `RUN mv build/libs/ComponentName-?.?.?.jar build/libs/app.jar` that says that the directory `build/libs/app.jar` doesn't exist.

I already looking in internet trying to find solutions and all said that is basically a Syntax problem but not really what I need, I'm new in all of this of Docker so I'm not sure what to do.

This is the dockerfile block:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 as builder
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ARG ARTIFACTORY_USER
ARG ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
COPY . /app
RUN ./gradlew build
RUN mv build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar build/libs/app.jar
RUN ls -l build/libs

FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/openjdk-17-runtime:latest
USER 0
RUN mkdir /app
RUN chown -R 185:0 /app
RUN microdnf update -y

USER 185
WORKDIR /app
ARG APP_NAME=Component-Name-k8s
COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/app.jar /app

# Start service
EXPOSE 8093
ENTRYPOINT java -jar app.jar
```

And this is the error that I'm recieving:

```
ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c mv build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar build/libs/app.jar" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [builder 6/7] RUN mv build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar build/libs/app.jar:
target 'build/libs/app.jar' is not a directory
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     COPY . /app
   7 |     RUN ./gradlew build
   8 | >>> RUN mv build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar build/libs/app.jar
   9 |     RUN ls -l build/libs
  10 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mv build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar build/libs/app.jar" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with docker. The problem is that `build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar` resolves to several files inside your container. Hence the `mv` target must be an existing directory in that case. You won't get the error if it matches a single file. See [this reproducible example](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/1b846b551519a090f71d1ed301ffa580)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have multiple files that match `build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar`.

In that case, you give 3 or more arguments to `mv`.

If you give 3 or more arguments to `mv`, the last argument has to be an existing diretory into which all other arguments are moved.

To make it work with wildcards, make sure to only match one file, for example by deleting `build/libs/Component-Name-?.?.?.jar` before running the build, or similar.

Comment: Thanks! That was my issue, I have more than one version of Component-Name in build/libs, do you have any recommendation for take the version that's actually at build.gradle? I also tried with     build/libs/Component-Name-$(./gradlew -q packageVersion).jar    but doesn't work.

Comment: Many ways lead to rome. You could e. g. right away name the jar as you need it within the Gradle build or with an extra Gradle task.